# Is it possible to rollback Tridion SP1 HR#1 to Tridion SP1

Tags: tridion

Is it possible to uninstall the Tridion SP1 HR#1 hotfix from the CMS and leave the DB Updates in place?  We experience very slow behavior of the GUI since applying the hotfix (maybe related to TMS service failing?) and need to go back to SP1 - however, we have made content updates to the DB since we applied the hotfix and would like to know if SP1 is compatible with the HR#1 DB Updates.

I realize this is a very specific issue - but maybe someone else has needed to rollback to SP1 for a different reason?

Comment: SP1 HR#1 is a hotfix **rollup**, which includes multiple hotfixes. It is by itself **not** a hotfix however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no supported way to roll back the upgrade nor is there a supported way to run an older version of the product on a newer database.

The closest you can probably get is restoring your database backup and install a plain SP1 on a new box. This is one of those cases where having a virtualized environment would help, since then you could probably roll back to your previous snapshot of the VM (similar to how you restore the database).

Comment: I think that by "DB Updates" Robert means content changes, not DB structure changes applied by HR1

Comment: Good point. I'm afraid the answer is the same though - and not just from a theoretical point of view. The database structure was significantly changed in HR1: the SQL update script is 863KB and most of it looks "fairly non-trivial".

Comment: My thoughts exactly on the DB rollback - huge SQL file.  I thought if it is only adding new cols, etc, then it could be possible.  Really too bad - since it has been a few days since the HR#1 was applied.  Not really an option now to go back to the old DB and lose all content since the hotfix was applied...will try to fix the HR#1 issues...maybe related to World Server Connector...

Comment: If there's no way back, the only way is forward. Did you log a ticket with CS about this poor performance?

Answer (score 1):

Problem was very slow GUI performance after applying HR#1.  On saving a Component the World Server Connector writes errors into the Tridion Event Log.  I opened a case with Customer Support and will update here when I have the solution.

Advice - if you are using the World Server Connector - do not install HR#1 yet.  Wait until a hotfix is created for this issue or a solution presented from Tridion.

We are not rolling back - just going forward!  :)  We'll leave the World Server Connector off the system until we can make sure HR#1 and the WSC are happily working together.

Comment: Good to hear that you found the root cause. There are so many parts to SDL's product suite that finding the cause is typically the most difficult part.